# How to plot Row.names on x axis with x and y columns on y axis?

Tags: r, plot

I have 3 columns, `Row.names`, `x`, and `y`.

How do I plot `Row.names` on the x axis with `x` and `y` on the y axis, to compare the lines of `x` vs `y`?

```
    Row.names                      x           y
1   bare_nuclei                   NA          NA
2   bland_chromatin         5.979253    2.100437
3   clump_thickness         7.195021    2.956332
4   marginal_adhesion       5.547718    1.364629
5   mitoses                 2.589212    1.063319
6   normal_nucleoli         5.863071    1.290393
7   single_eipthelial       5.298755    2.120087
8   uniformity_cell_shape   6.560166    1.443231
9   uniformity_cell_size    6.572614    1.325328
```

Comment: What do you intend to show by plotting a line for `x` and `y`? Plotting a line implies a trend, and as far as I can tell, these are discrete observations of different variables, meaning it would be fallacious to display the data with a line graph.

Comment: @Mako212 Maybe a histogram comparing the values of x and y for each Row.name? I just want to compare the values of x and y for each Row.name

Answer (score 3):

Let's use `ggplot2`:

R/ggplot2 needs to have the data in "long" format (meaning one observation per row) to create many types of graphs.

We use `melt` to make that transformation, using `Row.names` as the `id.vars`: `melt(data,id.vars="Row.names")`. Then we  assign the row names to the x axis, and the column generated by `melt`, called `value` to the y values. Finally, we use `geom_bar` to color your x and y values, and split them into separate bars, using `position="dodge"`.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)

df1 <- melt(data,"Row.names")

g1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = Row.names, y=value)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=variable),stat="identity", position ="dodge") + 
  theme_bw()+ 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=-40, hjust=.1))
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe because I can only use 3.1.1 of R, but I'm getting errors running this.  I can load the packages but when running the ggplot code, I get an error:                    "Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'variable' not found"

Comment: "Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'variable' not found"

Comment: @JoeJohnson what are the Column names of `df1` (the melted data)?

Comment: how do I find that out? When I do View(df1), I get an error "Error in View : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'"

Comment: never mind that error, the column names of df1 are: Row.names, variable, and value

Comment: then, when I run the ggplot code, I get this error:

Comment: Error in seq.default(from = best$lmin, to = best$lmax, by = best$lstep) : 
  'from' must be of length 1
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(diff(sort(x))) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf

Comment: @JoeJohnson Try running `df1[is.na(df1)]<- 0` before the `ggplot` code (replacing the NAs with zeros). It seems this is an old bug with the way `ggplot` handles NA values. It's fixed in newer versions, but apparently not yours.

Comment: that helped, but I have a problem. It looks like my Row.names column is formatted "AsIs" data type, while the other 2 are both numeric. So now when I run ggplot code, I get this error:

Comment: "Error in abs(x) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function"

Comment: as.factor, AHA I GOT IT!! Thanks!

Comment: @JoeJohnson Use `str(df1)` to view the data types for each column. Use `df1$Row.names <- as.factor(df1$Row.names)` to fix it if it's a weird data type.